# How to get the time taken for Clairvoyant restart?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, scip, sat

I am trying to get the time taken for Clairvoyant restart to occur in SCIP7.0.0, in order to compare the speed with another numerical method.

In `event_estim.c`, I have modified line 2792 to become `SCIPverbMessage(scip, SCIP_VERBLEVEL_HIGH, NULL, "Restart triggered after %d consecutive estimations that the remaining tree will be large. Time taken is %.3f \n", eventhdlrdata->restarthitcounter, SCIPclockGetTime(scip->stat->solvingtime));`

However, I get the following error after recompiling SCIP:

```
src/scip/event_estim.c: In function ‘eventExecEstim’:
src/scip/event_estim.c:2793:50: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SCIPclockGetTime’; did you mean ‘SCIPsolGetTime’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                eventhdlrdata->restarthitcounter, SCIPclockGetTime(scip->stat->solvingtime));             
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                  SCIPsolGetTime
src/scip/event_estim.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-unknown-warning-option’
```

I used SCIPclockGetTime with those arguments because I wanted the current solving time. Could somebody help me please? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: The function you are looking for is `SCIPgetSolvingTime(scip)`.

Longer answer: The function `SCIPclockGetTime()` is declared in the **private** header clock.h and should therefore not be directly used in plugins such as this event handler plugin. Instead, you could use `SCIPgetClockTime(scip, clockptr)`, (note the difference in the naming, "get" now comes first.) which is a public wrapper around `SCIPclockGetTime()`. For accessing the solving time clock, which is the most central clock object in SCIP, you can use the convenience method `SCIPgetSolvingTime(scip)`, such that you don't need to dereference scip->stat->solvingtime by yourself.

The reason for this wrapping is that the SCIP core internals can change, for example a new argument may be added to SCIPclockGetTime() in the future, or the solvingtime clock object may be moved to a different location. The public API, which the plugins use, need not be changed in such cases.